# How to deploy an app with multiple Docker containers to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django application whose docker image's `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/

ENV PORT=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

Then, I have a `docker-compose.yml` file for defining other container images and dependencies for my Django application as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: &django_app
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
  celery_worker:
    <<: *django_app
    command: celery -A DJingApp worker --loglevel=info
    ports: []
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

As you can see above, I've got to have 3 containers(`web`, `rabbitmq`, and `celery_worker`) running at any point in time for my Django app to work.

So, how do I deploy this project's Docker images to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and run them out there? Are there any changes that I will have to make to my `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`? If yes, what are they?

Comment: I'm not sure Beanstalk is what you want to use if you're trying to use docker-compose and docker containers.  Use ECS or EKS if you'd like to deploy a docker-based stack in AWS.

Comment: @2ps the AWS documentation says there is a way to deploy multi-container docker images to Beanstalk, but when I try it out, I'm getting a lot of errors and I think I'm doing it wrong. So, I wanted to know the correct step-by-step procedure for my situation. Please let me know if you get it cuz I'm just a beginner when it comes to AWS

Answer (score 1):

It's quite challenging to deploy a multi-container app to Elastic Beanstalk. You need a `Dockerrun.aws.json` version 2 configuration file which is an Elastic Beanstalk–specific JSON file that describes how to deploy a set of Docker containers as an Elastic Beanstalk application.

If you don't know how to create the configuration file I suggest reviewing the [official page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun).

And also you can use [container transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) utility to transform your `docker-compose` file to a `Dockerrun.aws.json` configuration file which I find very helpful. You may need to make some changes in the autogenerated file.

And also to customize your environment you need to use [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). Such as defining your Django settings path, WSGI path, web server configurations, executing Django management commands before deployment and so.

For detailed logs, I suggest using environment logs under:

*Elastic Beanstalk - Environments - 'your-environment-name' - Logs*

**Note**: I suggest using [eb deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) for successful deployment since you need to deploy your source code in `.zip` file format.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk now uses docker-compose instead of Dockerrun.aws.json